# clicking on webelement found with selenium java

Tags: java, html, selenium, if-statement

how can i get the webelement to be click based on data-key in the class `_3d5d`? to be more exact, if a user input the value 2002, it will have an error that tells the user "no such year, please enter again" and allow him to reenter the value. if the value keyed in matches the data-type, it will click the element.

html snippet from firebug

```
<div class="_5ay5">
    <div class="_18fs">
    <div id="PageScrubberPagelet_153681831442414"          
     data-referrer="PageScrubberPagelet_153681831442414">
         <div class="_4vm5 _5ay5">
            <ul id="u_0_62">
                 <li class="_3d5d">
                     <a id="u_0_5x" class="_3d5b" role="button" href="#" 
                     data-key="recent">Recent</a>
                 </li>
                 <li class="_3d5d">
                     <a id="u_0_5y" class="_3d5b _-fk" role="button" 
                     href="#" data-key="year_2015">2015</a>
                 </li>
                 <li class="_3d5d">
                     <a id="u_0_5z" class="_3d5b" role="button" href="#" 
                     data-key="year_2014">2014</a>
                 </li>
                 <li class="_3d5d">
                     <a id="u_0_60" class="_3d5b" role="button" href="#" 
                     data-key="year_2013">2013</a>
                  </li>
```

This is what i have attempted and it clicks on whatever year the user has input. However, this solution is sort of hard-coded where the year to be searched in coded. So, is there a way that will allow the year to be retrieved if its available in the html? Also, allow the user to re-input if there is no such year.

```
    Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);  // Reading from System.in
    System.out.println("Enter a year (YYYY): ");
    String year = reader.next(); // Scans the next token of the input as an int.


        if (year.contains("recent")){
            WebElement recent = dr.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(@data-key,'recent')]"));                        
            recent.click(); 
        }    
        else if (year.contains("2015")){
            WebElement year_2015 = dr.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(@data-key,'2015')]"));                           
            year_2015.click();
        }
        else if (year.contains("2014")){
            WebElement year_2014 = dr.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(@data-key,'2014')]"));                           
            year_2014.click();
        }             
        else if (year.contains("2013")){
            WebElement year_2013 = dr.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(@data-key,'2013')]"));                        
            year_2013.click(); 
        }
```

Comment: What have you tried and what was the result? As you did in school... please show your work. :) It's part of the process of getting questions answered on SO. It's helpful to you because it forces you to investigate your own problem and think it through. It also proves to readers that you did your homework and made a reasonable attempt to answer your own question. Thirdly, it helps readers find and diagnose the problem resulting in a better answer for you and less time wasted for us.

Comment: @JeffC Thank you for your suggestion, i have edited and shown my work as shown above.

Comment: Does xpath not working?

Comment: xpath works, just that im looking for a way that if the user input matches the xpath, it will click on the xpath. in the solution i have written requires me to write down all the possible year in an if-else statement. but if let's say i do not know if there are any other year and hence did not code it down, this would meant that user cannot click the element on any other year as i did not code it @HelpingHands

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException;

Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);  // Reading from System.in
System.out.println("Enter a year (YYYY): ");
String year = reader.nextInt();

try {
    WebElement yearButton = dr.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(@data-key,'" + year + "')]"));                        
    yearButton.click(); 
} catch(NoSuchElementException e) {
    System.out.println("Element does not exist!");
}
```